# How to apply OR operation to all elements of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I was going through a Java exercise and found out that they are asking for a subset of an array whose sum is equal to the "**OR of the array**" (applying OR operation to all elements of an array). 
But I am unable to find out how to calculate "`OR{1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`". 
Can anybody help me in understanding this concept?

Comment: Can the subset be of any size? Or does it have to be specifically, let's say 2, or 3 numbers that add up to 7?

Comment: Or-ing all the elements of this array together with the `|` operator gives 7.

Comment: See also [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can compute OR of all elements in your array as follows:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int result = arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    result |= arr[i];
System.out.println(result); // 7
```

The '`|`' operator is used for OR in Java.

```
1 = 0001
OR
2 = 0010
OR
3 = 0011
OR
4 = 0100
OR
5 = 0101
-------- EQUALS
7 = 0111
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like OR operator between the members of the array

```
 1 = 001
 2 = 010
 3 = 011
 4 = 100
 5 = 101
```

Or between all `1|2|3|4|5 = 111 = 7`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the `or` operator stands for.
It's very likely a logical disjunction of the binary values of those numbers.

```
int i = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
```